# Blocking Datatables initial table loading display with a loading gif

Tags: javascript, html, django, datatables

I have a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) template html page that includes a form for users to upload a data file in JSON format. This data file is then processed, and the data is sent to my [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database. The page displays a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/download/) table populated by data from the database and three [D3](https://d3js.org/) charts.

Currently, when I upload a file, I can see the datatable in its raw form for several seconds before the table is fully created. As the table is large, it obscures my D3 chart's initial animations. Ideally, I would like the initial datatable creation to be obscured by a 'loading.gif'. When the datatable creation is complete, I want the user to see the fully formed datatable, and only then do I want the D3 charts to be created/rendered on the page.

I have included a loading.gif in my static folder, which correctly displays after file upload. However, after several seconds, the loading.gif disappears, and then, as before, I can briefly see the data in its raw form before the full datatable displays. I am unsure how to completely obscure the datatable creation (with the loading.gif) until the table is fully formed.

Here is my DataTables script (below). As you can see, I have a 'loading' indicator at the top of the script set to 'block,' and I set it to 'none' when the datatable is complete. I thought this would obscure the table creation until it was complete, but this is not the case.

```html
<!-- DATATABLES -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('form').submit(function () {
            // Show the loading indicator
            $('#loading-indicator').css('display', 'block');
          });

          var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            colReorder: true,
            fixedColumns: false,
            responsive: false,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: '40vh',
            scrollX: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            pageLength: 15,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
              {
                extend: 'colvis',
                postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
                text: 'Column Selection'
              },
              {
                text: 'Download CSV',
                extend: 'csv',
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: ':visible'
                }
              }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
              { width: '60px', targets: 0, className: 'text-left' },
              { width: '200px', targets: -1, className: 'text-left' }
            ],
            initComplete: function () {
              $('#loading-indicator').css('display', 'none');
              $('#example_wrapper').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Here is my full html template page:

```html
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}">

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.13.4/b-2.3.6/b-colvis-2.3.6/b-html5-2.3.6/cr-1.6.2/r-2.4.1/sb-1.4.1/sp-2.1.2/sl-1.6.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.13.4/b-2.3.6/b-colvis-2.3.6/b-html5-2.3.6/cr-1.6.2/r-2.4.1/sb-1.4.1/sp-2.1.2/sl-1.6.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'd3_dots.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'd3_bar.js' %}"></script>
  <style>
    #example_wrapper {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    table {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
      padding: 1px;
      background: white;
      color: white;
    }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dt-button-collection .buttons-columnVisibility .dt-button.active {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .text-left {
      text-align: left !important;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .buttons-collection .dt-button:first-child {
      background-color: red !important;
      color: white !important;
    }
    .buttons-csv {
      background-color: red !important;
      color: white !important;
    }
    .upload-form button {
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #E9ECEF;
      border: 1px solid #CED4DA;
    }
    .bar {
      fill: #0c6cfc;
      stroke:  #FFA500;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .bar:hover {
      fill: #FFA500;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    #chart-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    #chart-level-assign,
    #chart-edu-setting
    #chart-smd-scatter {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    #loading-indicator {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
      z-index: 9999;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 20%;
      background-image: url('/static/loading.gif');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
    }
  #loading-indicator img {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading-indicator">
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row mb-3">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form.json_file }}
          </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-left justify-content-end">
                <button type="submit" name="upload_button" class="btn-primary">Upload</button>
              </div>
        </div>
      </form>
        {% if has_data %}
        <br>
          <table id="example" class="display hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>EPPI ID</th>
                <th>Admin Strand</th>
                <th>Educational Setting</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for data_object in data %}
                <tr>
                  <th>{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                  <td>{{ data_object.eppi_id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ data_object.admin_strand_data }}</td>
                  <td>{{ data_object.edu_setting_data }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% empty %}
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">No data to display.</td>
                </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="chart-wrapper">
        <div id="chart-level-assign"></div>
        <div id="chart-edu-setting"></div>
        <div id="chart-smd-scatter"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- DATATABLES -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('form').submit(function () {
            // Show the loading indicator
            $('#loading-indicator').css('display', 'block');
          });
        
          var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            colReorder: true,
            fixedColumns: false,
            responsive: false,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: '40vh',
            scrollX: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            pageLength: 15,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
              {
                extend: 'colvis',
                postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
                text: 'Column Selection'
              },
              {
                text: 'Download CSV',
                extend: 'csv',
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: ':visible'
                }
              }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
              { width: '60px', targets: 0, className: 'text-left' },
              { width: '200px', targets: -1, className: 'text-left' }
            ],
            initComplete: function () {
              $('#loading-indicator').css('display', 'none');
              $('#example_wrapper').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
      
      
      
      <!-- D3 CHARTS -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // First chart
        const assign_level_rawData = JSON.parse('{{ assign_levels|safe }}');
        console.log(assign_level_rawData)
        for (let i = 0; i < assign_level_rawData.length; i++) {
          if (assign_level_rawData[i][0] === "N") {
            assign_level_rawData[i][0] = "NA";
          }
        }
        const data1 = assign_level_rawData.map(d => ({level_assign: d[0], count: d[1]}));
        createChart(data1, "chart-level-assign", "Level of Assignment", "level_assign");
        
        // Second chart
        const edu_setting_rawData = JSON.parse('{{ edu_setting_levels|safe }}');
        for (let i = 0; i < edu_setting_rawData.length; i++) {
          if (edu_setting_rawData[i][0] === "N") {
            edu_setting_rawData[i][0] = "NA";
          }
        }
        const data2 = edu_setting_rawData.map(d => ({edu_setting: d[0], count: d[1]}));
        createChart(data2, "chart-edu-setting", "Educational Setting", "edu_setting");

        // Third chart
        const data3 = "{{ smd_combined_csv|escapejs }}";
        const smd = d3.csvParse(data3).filter(d => d.smd_value !== "NA");
        drawDotChart(smd);
      </script>
        

</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the DataTable is loading, you can also use the `processing` option to display a loading message or animation instead of initComplete and draw.

```js
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  // Some other code
  processing: true,
  language: {
    processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Data Loading...'
  }
});
```

Here we define processing as true and display a loading message using the language option. The custom message will be automatically deleted after the DataTable is loaded.

You can personalize the loading message. In this snippet, a spinner animation is displayed using an icon from the Font Awesome icon set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use “draw” event delegate instead of “initComplete”.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('form').submit(function () {
            // Show the loading indicator
            $('#loading-indicator').css('display', 'block');
          });

          var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            colReorder: true,
            fixedColumns: false,
            responsive: false,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: '40vh',
            scrollX: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            pageLength: 15,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
              {
                extend: 'colvis',
                postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
                text: 'Column Selection'
              },
              {
                text: 'Download CSV',
                extend: 'csv',
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: ':visible'
                }
              }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
              { width: '60px', targets: 0, className: 'text-left' },
              { width: '200px', targets: -1, className: 'text-left' }
            ]
          });
          table.on('draw', function () {
             $('#loading-indicator').css('display', 'none');
             $('#example_wrapper').css('visibility', 'visible');
           });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include the "my codes" part to your example? I am attempting this method but my table isn't loading at all doing it this way (so far).

Comment: i edited my answer to include full datatable initialization.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this does not work. The loading screen does appear but as it is removed there is a brief (approx 1.5 second) delay where I can see the raw data prior to datatable creation.